# Display PDF document within web app iframe on iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf, iframe

I have an HTML5 web app running on webkit browsers.  The app contains an iframe used to display pdf documents (and other documents such as images etc).  I set the src of the iframe to the pdf or image.  On an iPad with no pdf reading software the iframe is blank - it seems an iPad out of the box has no ability to display pdfs.

Given the iframe context, what are my options for displaying the pdf (and other docs) on the ipad?

Thanks.